# Are envelope resent and recipient resent webhook events triggered for automated reminders?

Tags: docusignapi

After following the [webhook event triggers documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/event-triggers/), I'd like to know if the `envelope_resent` and `recipient_resent` events are triggered for automated reminders, given that the automated reminders are set up on creation of the evenlope?

In my case, I'd be configuring the reminders on creation of the signature request, and I'd like to perform some follow-up actions in my own system whenever a signer is reminded of a document they have to sign. `envelope_resent`/`recipient_resent` look like they could do this for me, but the documentation implies that this event is only triggered when the envelope is "resent via the UI or via the `Envelopes:update` API call".

Could anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification on envelope_resent and recipient_resent events

While the envelope_resent and recipient_resent events sound like they might be useful for tracking signer reminders, that's not quite their purpose.  These events are specifically triggered when a sender intentionally resends an envelope, either through the DocuSign user interface (UI) or by using the Envelopes:update API call.

In your scenario where automated reminders are set up during envelope creation, these events won't fire when those reminders are sent.

Comment: OK, thanks @MikeMej. Is there any other existing way to track signature reminders?